# Generating a string in a particular format by reading data from a map

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, guava

I have a `processToTaskIdHolder` Map which contains `processId` as the key and `taskId` as the value. Now I am iterating this map and at the end I am making a String in particular format.

For example:-

- Let's say I have 123 as the key and 009 is the value in the `processToTaskIdHolder` map.
- Now I will make a "activityKey" using 123 and then get data basis on this key.
- Now I will iterate all the categories for that `activityKey` and check whether those `categoryId` are already present in `processToTaskIdHolder` keyset or not. If they are present, then I will extract taskId for that `categoryId` from the map and also extract score for that `categoryId` and store it in an `Info` class.
- Same category can be present with different score for different `processId`.

Now I need to repeat above steps for each activity I have in `activities` list.

So my formatted string will be like this:-

```
A,B,C:Score1,D:Score2
P,Q,R:Score1,S:Score2
```

- Where A is the `categoryId` for the `processId` C and D, and `Score1` is the score for `categoryId` A for `processId` C. `Score2` is the score for `categoryId` A but for `processId` D. We have different scores for same categories for two different processes. It means, `categoryId` A was present in both `processId` C and D so I need to get the score for both the cases and make a string like that. And B is the `taskId` for `categoryId` A which will be present in the map.
- Where P is the `categoryId` for the `processId` R and S, and `Score1` is the score for `categoryId` P for `processId` R. `Score2` is the score for `categoryId` P but for `processId` S. We have different scores for same categories for two different processes. It means, `categoryId` P was present in both `processId` R and S so I need to get the score for both the cases and make a string like that. And Q is the `taskId` for `categoryId` P which will be present in the map.

I have this code which does the job but I think it's not the right and efficient way to achieve above formatted string. I believe it can be done in a much better way.

```
  private static final List<String> activities = Arrays.asList("tree", "gold", "print", "catch");

  public static void reverseLookup(final String clientId, final Map<String, String> processToTaskIdHolder) {
    Multimap<String, Info> reverseLookup = LinkedListMultimap.create();
    for (String activity : activities) {
      for (Entry<String, String> entry : processToTaskIdHolder.entrySet()) {
        String activityKey = "abc_" + activity + "_" + clientId + "_" + entry.getKey();
        Optional<Datum> datum = getData(activityKey);
        if (!datum.isPresent()) {
          continue;
        }
        List<Categories> categories = datum.get().getCategories();
        for (Categories category : categories) {
          String categoryId = String.valueOf(category.getLeafCategId());
          if (processToTaskIdHolder.containsKey(categoryId)) {
            Info info = new Info(entry.getKey(), String.valueOf(category.getScore()));
            reverseLookup.put(categoryId + ":" + processToTaskIdHolder.get(categoryId), info);
          }
        }
      }
      String formattedString = generateString(reverseLookup);
      System.out.println(formattedString);
    }
  }

  private static String generateString(final Multimap<String, Info> reverseLookup) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Entry<String, Collection<Info>> entry : reverseLookup.asMap().entrySet()) {
      sb.append(entry.getKey().split(":")[0]).append(",").append(entry.getKey().split(":")[1])
          .append(",");
      String sep = "";
      for (Info info : entry.getValue()) {
        sb.append(sep).append(info.getLeafCategoryId()).append(":").append(info.getScore());
        sep = ",";
      }
      sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

In the `reverseLookup` map, I have a key in this format - "a:b", so I'm not sure instead of making a key like that. Maybe it can be done in some other better way?

**Note:** I am working with Java 7. `Categories` and `Info` class is a simple immutable class with basic `toString` implementations.

Comment: *"Note: I am working with Java 7."* - Java 7 has been end-of-lifed by Oracle.  It is time you / your organization made the move.  The longer you leave it, the harder it will get.

Comment: Yeah until my organization makes a move, I am stuck with Java7 but I am sure we will start using Java8 very soon.

Comment: Could you drop the snippet you provided here in an absolutely new project on your machine and see what it says missing? Maybe a simplified version of each class mentioned in your code, so it works in IDE. Meanwhile, I'll rethink the logic you've described here.

Comment: What I have not provided is - `Info` and `Categories` classes. You can assume that they are immutable classes.

Answer (score 1):

This looks horrible heavy for me with this "formates"
 - instead of creating info i d just create a string what will be printed like:  `String info = entry.getKey() +categoryId + String.valueOf(category.getScore());`
 - Then having Multimap map just:

```
 map.asMap().entrySet().stream().forEach( e->System.out.println(e));
```

Or this in 1.7 like:
Like:

```
public static<M,N> String entryLnInvert(Map<M,N> map, String keyFormat, String between, String valueFormat) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        for( Entry<M,N> e: map.entrySet()) {
            sb.append(String.format(valueFormat,e.getValue()));         
            sb.append(between);
            sb.append(String.format(keyFormat,e.getKey()));         
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

and other crap you just put in toString() of N,M classes
 such printout would be enoph for me

Comment: I am working with Java7 so can't use Java8 unfortunately. Yeah I know it might not be efficient way so that's why I was trying to see if there is any better way. Can you provide an example basis on my code in Java7 to make myself clear?

Comment: This method will replace which of my method? Still confuse how does this method is being used and from where it is being called. Do you think you can provide an example with my code to make it more clear?

Comment: both, dont convert a map to another map for printout.
also java 7 easy becomes java8 if you define your own functor like:
interface Formatter<N,String> {public String format(N value)  and use it as additional parameter in entryLnInvert

Comment: yeah agreed but I am not able to understand how to use your suggestion to do that. Do you think you can edit your suggestion basis on my code so that I can understand how it will work? As of now I am confuse on how this will work.

Comment: i dont understad your code fully, also where the     Collection<String> activities comes from.

Comment: where is Collection<String>? I do have Collection<Info> object right? Since I am using MultiMap right so value can be Collection of Info objects given its key.

Comment: for (String activity : activities) 
what is that

Comment: @user8426627: `where the Collection<String> activities comes from`: declared and initialised in the very first line of code. (And if it was wrapped as an `UnmodifiableList`, you'd *think* it never changed.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all. If you don't understand things right away, usually it means code is messy. Code gets messy when you don't have time to think and you just need to do it. I've refactored junior/mids code and even seniors code produced when people just want to do it right away and don't have time to think.
  So for the future. The way you approach is this is start simplifying, make the method do one thing. Get rid of repetitive parts. 
  So with first iteration I refactored to this

```
public class CategoryHolder {

// when in your code you have System.getProperty() called many times - do you need that? 
// Its not changing every second, so when you store in variable, you're good then
private static final String END_OF_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
// you used "," many times - its called magic string or if some number 
// is jumping here and there in code its called magic number
// when you define the variable then you change in ONE place when something changes
private static final String COMMA = ",";
// same here, name is stupid maybe, but it's better than ":" all around your code
// rename it to something more meaningful
private static final String DOUBLE_DOT = ":";
private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";

// I don't like the name of the method, but ok, its a first iteration of refactoring
private static String generateString(final Multimap<String, Info> reverseLookup) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<Info>> entry : reverseLookup.asMap().entrySet()) {
        String[] splitThing = entry.getKey().split(DOUBLE_DOT);
        // I started to simplify and immediately seen you do split two times
        // while it could be done only once.. good catch
        // you might use some meaningful names, I just don't know much about your domain
        String something1 = splitThing[0]; // your doing split two times?
        // same here
        String something2 = splitThing[1];
        sb.append(something1).append(COMMA).append(something2).append(COMMA);

        createInfoString(sb, entry);

        sb.append(END_OF_LINE);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private static void createInfoString(StringBuilder sb, Map.Entry<String, Collection<Info>> entry) {
    // I guess you've made it as the case to "" for first but "," for all next
    // I would probably go with for(int i=0; i<entry.length? ; i++){
    // separator = i == 0 ? EMPTY_STRING : DOUBLE_DOT;
    String separator = EMPTY_STRING;
    for (Info info : entry.getValue()) {
        sb.append(separator)
        sb.append(info.getLeafCategoryId())
        sb.append(DOUBLE_DOT).append(info.getScore());
        separator = COMMA;
    }
}
```

It's a first step, but looks a bit more clear for me.

Now we do a bit more refactoring and its starts to get more clear what we do here

```
public class DataFormatter {

private static final String END_OF_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
private static final String COMMA = ",";
private static final String DOUBLE_DOT = ":";
private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
private static final int NICE_PART_1_INDEX = 0;
private static final int NICE_PART_2_INDEX = 1;

private static String format(final Multimap<String, Info> reverseLookup) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<Info>> entry : reverseLookup.asMap().entrySet()) {
        formatKey(sb, entry.getKey());
        formatValue(sb, entry);
        sb.append(END_OF_LINE);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

private static void formatKey(StringBuilder sb, String key) {
    String[] splitThing = key.split(DOUBLE_DOT);
    String something1 = splitThing[NICE_PART_1_INDEX];
    String something2 = splitThing[NICE_PART_2_INDEX];

    sb.append(something1).append(COMMA).append(something2).append(COMMA);
}

private static void formatValue(StringBuilder sb, Map.Entry<String, Collection<Info>> entry) {
    String separator = EMPTY_STRING;

    for (Info info : entry.getValue()) {
        sb.append(separator);
        sb.append(info.getLeafCategoryId()).append(DOUBLE_DOT).append(info.getScore());
        separator = COMMA;
    }
}
```

At the end, I added formatting code to class and called DataFormatter and format() method. If you would have formatting in 5 different places you could move them to this class, see common parts, reuse them rather than copy/paste similar code in many places.

I would say - add unit tests which would pass any bad thing into your method you could imagine. Then you will be sure that your code works fine.